# Dynamic Lpad for two digit decimal in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having this query and which is showing zeros to the `lpad` of the output

```
SELECT '000000000000' || TO_CHAR(rlseamt,'FM9999999999D00') Transaction_Amount 
  FROM ln01mast
```

I want it put zeros dynamically, ex: If the number is 188888 it should appear as 000000188888.00

Answer (score 1):

Use a format mask with initial zeros:  `TO_CHAR(rlseamt, 'FM00000000000009D00')`